# Ruby regex: "capture string unless it is followed by..."

Tags: ruby, regex

My regex captures quoted phrases:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

I want to improve it, by ignoring quotes, which are followed by ', -' (a comma, a space and a dash in this particular order).

How do I do this?

The test: http://rubular.com/r/xls6vN1w92

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it, using a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"(?!, -)([^"]*)"(?!, -)
```

A little icky, but it works. You want to make sure either quote isn't followed by your string, or else the match will start at the closing quotes.

http://rubular.com/r/yFMyUKJOHL

Comment: This is the best solution so far - it will only fail if a string happens to start with `, -` which is not very probable...

Comment: @Tim - ohh. Good point. But then the `"([^"]*)"(?!, -)` seemingly wrong result might be considered valid, since you introduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**

`"(.*?)"(?!, -)`

**Working Example**

http://rubular.com/r/9kOmZLxLfy

Comment: This only works if there is at most one pair of quotes per line.

Comment: ... and, doesn't work if quotes can span multiple lines. If these aren't the cases, this is a good solution.

Comment: I just enhanced the OP regex to do what he wanted. All those flaws you mention are present in the original regex too

Answer (score 1):

This is unparsable in your context, its open ended. The only way to parse it is to consume the not's as well as the want's, but its still an invalid premise.

`/"([^"]*?)"(?!, -)|"[^"]*?"(?=, -)/`

Then check for capture group 1 on each match, something like this:

```
$rx = qr/"([^"]*?)"(?!, -)|"[^"]*?"(?=, -)/;
while (' "ingnore me", - "but not me" ' =~ /$rx/g) {
  print "'$1'\n" if defined $1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `(?!...)` at the end of the regex:

```
"([^"\n]*)"(?!, -)
```

Comment: I thought of that, too, but this only works if there is exactly one pair of quotes per line...

Comment: I've also replaced `[^"]` with `[^"\n]` to prevent newlines in qoutes. Another way to avoid this could be something like `"(\b[^"]*\b)"(?!, -)`.